# Syntax Error in Java print statement

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"\))");
```

I am getting an error. I want to print above statement as a string.
Can someone help me.

Comment: Can you share the *exact* error with us?

Comment: P.S. You have too many `\ `s.

Comment: no need to escape ')' at end of the line.

Comment: @Trobbins: I know what the error is, I was trying to get the OP to add it to their question :-P

Comment: String v11 = "John"; System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"))"); // I want to replace "LCSP" with v11 how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last backslash `\` there is no need to escape `)`

```
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"))");
```

[**DEMO1**](http://ideone.com/fLD74R)

Solution to the problem given in comment

```
String v11 = "John";
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\\\"concept:name\\\" value=\\\""+v11+"\\\"/>\"))");
```

OUTPUT

```
if(line.contains("<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"John\"/>"))
```

[**DEMO2**](http://ideone.com/v21lKW)

Comment: String v11 = "John";
    System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"))");
    
    // I want to replace "LCSP" with v11 how to do this

Comment: @vtammy updated my answer check `DEMO2`

Comment: String v11 = "John1"; System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value="+v11+"/>\"))"); My output should be: if(line.contains("<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"John1\"/>")) Any help, how to correct this

Comment: @vtammy check the link http://ideone.com/v21lKW

Answer (score 0):

no need to escape ')' at end of the line.

the changed statement is:

```
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"))");
```

Comment: System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"\))");

Comment: There is syntax error. ANy help

Comment: ya it have syntax erro, I had wrote the comment, just read that.

Answer (score 0):

Original

```
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"**\**))");
```

**** is not required I have removed from Original

Changed:

```
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"LCSP\"/>\"))");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String v11 = "John1";
System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\\\"concept:name\\\" value=\\\""+v11+"\\\"/>\"))");
```

remove the last backlash and update the "LCSP" to `v11` variable.

**output:**

```
if(line.contains("<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"John1\"/>"))
```

Comment: Not getting any output.

Comment: @vtammy check the answer now. Update with the variable `v11`.

Comment: String v11 = "John1";
   
   System.out.println("if(line.contains(\"<string key=\"concept:name\" value="+v11+"/>\"))");
   
My output should be:

if(line.contains("<string key=\"concept:name\" value=\"John1\"/>"))

Any help, how to correct this

Comment: @vtammy check it now.

Comment: @vtammy my answer. I have updated with what you need.

Comment: @vtammy This time it worked right ??